# Why do the time complexity of graph algorithms use |E| instead of using |V|^2?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra, bellman-ford

Shouldn't the time complexity of Dijkstra's algorithm and Bellman Ford algorithm be `O(|V|^2)` and `O(|V|^3)` respectively? I have been reading both their pseudo code from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode).

Both Bellman Ford algorithm and Dijkstra's algorithm look quite alike except for Bellman Ford algorithm doing the same process as Dijkstra's algorithm for `|V|` times (where `|V|` is the number of nodes). So why did every article I visit on this topic says that Dijkstra's algorithm runs in `O(|v|^2)` and Bellman Ford algorithm runs at `O(|V||E|)` time complexity? Where did I go wrong (if I really did)?

Update: 
Don't you think:
`|E| = (|V|^2 - |V|)/ 2` if each node is connected to each other node? So let's assume every node to be connected with every other node. Now we get, `O(|V|^3)` for Bellman Ford Algorithm. Am I right?

So we have `O(|V||E|)` = `O(|V|(|V|^2 - |V|)/2) = O(|V|^3)`. Is that right? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: This question belongs in Computer Science, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the time complexity of Dijkstra's algorithm and Bellman Ford
>   algorithm be O(|V|^2)  and O(|V|^3) respectively?

Yes<sup>(1)</sup>, but that won't be a tight bound. Similarly, you could say it is `O(|V|^5)`, and it will also be correct (recall that big O is asymptotic upper bound, not a tight one). 

Many graphs are not dense, but sparse, and the number of edges connected to each vertex is sub-linear. So, if we use the |E| notation as well, we can get a better more tight (and more informative) bound.

Similarly, think of an algorithm that traverses a matrix of size `nxm`. It is more informative to say the algorithm is `O(n*m)`, rather than saying it's `O(max{n,m}^2)`, isn't it?

Regarding implementation of Dijkstra's-Algorithm, the actual complexity depends a lot on the modify value in the min heap implementation, while there are implementations that can do it in logarithmic time (giving total of `O(|E|+|V|log|V|)` time, some implementations don't bother and just go for the simpler solution that runs in `O(|V|^2)`.

---

(1) Assuming simple graphs here

Comment: So  we say O(|V|^2) for Dijkstra's algorithm because it does not always have to check every path on the graph (if it finds the destination node sooner), but we say O(|E||V|) for Bellman Ford algorithm because it has to compulsorily check each node on the graph to find the shortest path (to keep the bound as tight as possible), Am I right? (and thanks)

Comment: @user3633270 No. Dijkstra's algorithm have implementations that are `O(|E|+|V|log|V|)`, and others that are `O(|V|^2+|E|) = O(|V|^2)` (for simple graphs), depending on the underlying DS used. BellmanFord has pretty much one implementation (and few variations of it) that is `O(|E|*|V|)`, without dependency on some external DS>

Comment: @amit Are these tighter bounds big theta: both *as big as* (big omega) and *as as small as* (big O)?